how to track component calling in Angular store application
working on a huge angular application which uses angular store. a popup is opened on in click and dispatch a action for showing data. now the popup is displayed with other activity on the application as well . how to track from where its calling or is there tool where we can see which component is calling from where.
I have tried to debug the application but not got much info. also tried with the redux tool.
